# AddFlat map of struct

Tags: go, redis

How to unmarshal map of struct?

added a  `map[string]` of `Person` type to redis using

```
conn.Do("HMSET", redis.Args{"Teams"}.AddFlat(values)...);
```

I am able to print a value

```
v, err := redis.String(conn.Do("HGET", key, field))
```

`log.Print(v)` succesfully prints the value, but how can I unmarshal it back to struct of type `Person`?

How I added

```
m:= make(map[string]Person)
m['E21']=Person{"FirstName","LastName"}
HMSet("Team", m)
```

How I added to redis

```
func HMSet(key string, values map[string]dataobjects.Person) error {
    conn := Pool.Get()
    defer conn.Close()
    if _, err := conn.Do("HMSET", redis.Args{key}.AddFlat(values)...); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return nil
}
```

How I got it back

```
func HGet(key, field string) error {
    conn := Pool.Get()
    defer conn.Close()

    v, err := redis.Bytes(conn.Do("HGET", key, field))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return err
    }
    // I am able to print v succesfully,but how to return Person object from v


    return nil
}
```

My struct

```
type Person struct {
    FirstName string  `FirstName `
    LastName string  `LastName `     
}
```

Comment: with `json.Unmarshal`

Comment: It throws invalid character 0 if I used json.Unmarshal(v, &t) where v is as stated above  t is of type Person

Comment: can you printout Person ?

Comment: Yes its succesfully prints the data for eg

Comment: i meant write person struct here :))

Comment: I Updated the code  in the question section could you check?

Comment: Did you consider using rejson module? https://oss.redislabs.com/rejson/

Answer (score 0):

```
func marshal(in interface{}) []byte {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    encoder := gob.NewEncoder(&buf)

    err := encoder.Encode(in)
    assert.Nil(err)

    return buf.Bytes()
}

func unmarshal(data []byte) Person {
    buffer := bytes.NewBuffer(data)
    decoder := gob.NewDecoder(buffer)

    var p Person
    err := decoder.Decode(p)
    assert.Nil(err)

    return p
}
```

you can use these to marshal your structs, swap person with your map, also make sure your struct has struct tags and capitalized first character of each field

Comment: Actually I want to avoid marshalling the struct ,because I have like 10000 records, and when i tried marshalling(using json) it was taking more time.so i tried to AddFlat and directly whole map to redis

Comment: does your person fields contain struct tags ?

Comment: Nope , let me try with tags. But how can still Marshall it if I have tags

Comment: wouldnt give you zero if it does

Comment: Sure let me try

Comment: Still the same when i Print am getting this {   0 0} , I updated my struct under my question